# React: How to load components properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am working on a simple app in react with ES6 and babel. Recently I faced this issue. I used `react-notifications` package here: https://github.com/minhtranite/react-notifications

I just followed the docs and it works fine. I can import it with `import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';`

But then I tried to work with this: https://github.com/cezary/react-loading

Now in the example of react-loading, the developer isn't using the ES6 way to get the component. I tried to look at the JS file and tried this after doing `npm install react-loading`:

`import {Loading} from 'react-loading';` but somehow this doesn't work. I get this:

> You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in

But I can see it is exported. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should do this instead: `import Loading from 'react-loading';`

Comment: @SaugatAcharya of course! the component is exported as default. thanks. I'll accept your answer if you publish

Comment: @AmitTeli yes I am. as @SaugatAcharaya said there is no need to do `{Loading}`. that component is exported as default. It works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a single module, it is exported as default. You'll have to do this:

```
import Loading from 'react-loading';
```